# How to find the cause of "second operation started on this thread..." error messsage

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core-3.1

We are converting an old .Net Framework 4.7.2 MVC app to .Net 5.  Until everything is converted, we have a number of the projects set up as NetStandard 2.  One of those projects is our data layer and the latest version of EF Core it can use is 3.1.

In the web app, there's a page that when loaded, has 2 ajax calls.  When the page loads one  of the 2 calls fail with the error - A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.  I've gone through both methods from front to back and everything is set up properly with async/await.  I've set up logging so I can see every query that's executed by the web app and verified nothing else is running that should already be using the thread.

This was not a problem in the .Net Framework/EF6 version so I've been banging my head against the wall for two days trying to trace what's causing this.

Since these are ajax calls, aren't they all considered their own request?  If so, I would expect the DI to provide a new context for each one.

Here's the javascript.

```
const loadPerDiem = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch("/Quote/PerDiemRates")
            .then(r => {
                let json = r.json();
                json.then(d => {
                    d.forEach((x) => {
                        var enumId = x.PerDiemEnumerationId;
                        var rate = x.Rate;

                        perDiemItems.forEach((y) => {
                            if (y.id == enumId)
                                y.rate = rate;
                        });
                    });
                    resolve(true);
                })
            });
    })
}

const getNetworks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch("/Quote/GetNetworks")
            .then(r => {
                r.json()
                    .then(d => {
                        networks = d;
                        resolve(true);
                    })
            });
    })
}

Promise.all([loadPerDiem(), getNetworks()])
        .then(r => {
            fetch("/QuoteAddOns/GetAllActive?v=" + new Date().getTime())
                .then(a => {
                    loadSavedQuotes();
                })
        })
```

And here are the endpoints being called.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PerDiemRates()
{
    return Json(await _onlineQuoteParameterService.PerDiemRatesAsync());
}

public async Task<JsonResult> GetNetworks()
{
    return Json(await _splitNetworkService.GetNetworksForDropDownAsync());
}
```

Here's the slimmed down version of our registry file where the context is registered for the DI container.

```
public void Define()
{
    Scan(
        scan =>
        {
            scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();

            scan.Assembly(ApplicationAssemblyName);
            foreach (var name in Assemblies)
                scan.Assembly(name);

            scan.AddAllTypesOf<IEventSubscriber>();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

    var entityNotifier = new EntityUpdateNotifier(channelService, exchangeService);
    For<IFHDbContext>().Use(new FHDbContext(DataSources.FHDataSource, entityNotifier));

}
```

Comment: What is the web framework? ASP.NET Core? Can you show is register the DbContext service?

Comment: Have you checked the thread and/or task windows in the debugger to see what other tasks are going on? Or checked that new dbContext objects are *actually* created for each call? (see MakeObjectID feature).

Comment: "I would expect the DI to provide a new context for each one." depends on how you added your DBContext to the DI container (and also which DI container you're using)

Comment: It's a .net 5 web app, so the successor of asp.net core.  @JonasH, yes I've checked everything I can find and in the logging I'm only seeing these two queries executing.  Whichever one hits second fails.  As for checking to see if a new db context object is actually created, I'm not sure how to do that.  I added the relevant portion of our registry file where the context is added to the container.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to add some logging to your FHDbContext constructor, or to add add a Guid-field to the DbContext that is set in the ctor to give you a unique id per object you can refer to.

Comment: I was just reading the Lamar docs and came across this - HttpContext related scopes are no longer supported... so it makes me think that it is the same context being used by both calls.  I think we'd need to change it to Transient.  My only question there is, is the context the same used for the entire life of the request - meaning any repo calls that are part of it?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Comment: @geoffswartz: You'll want Scoped. And I also recommend just using the ASP.NET DI; Microsoft attempted but IMO failed to make it truly replaceable, and you'll save yourself quite a bit of pain by just using the ASP.NET DI (at least for all the ASP.NET types).

Comment: @JonasH, thanks.  That confirmed I'm getting the same context for both calls.

Comment: @StephenCleary the reason we were using Lamar was because we have literally hundreds of services and repos that need added to the container.  We didn't want to have to worry about always remembering to update a startup file with a new service or repo.  Using the ASP.NET DI would require us to manually register each one while Lamar can handle that by scanning our assemblies.

Comment: It seems the fix was changing this line
For<IFHDbContext>().Use(new FHDbContext(DataSources.FHDataSource, entityNotifier));
to this 
For<IFHDbContext>().Use<FHDbContext>();